# How do I debug a reduce/reduce error in my bnf notation in Jison

Tags: syntax, bison, bnf

I'm writing bnf notation with Jison and getting an reduce/reduce conflict:

```
Conflict at state: 26, token: SIMPLE_ASSIGN
reduce by rule: PrimaryExpression -> Identifier
reduce by rule: LeftHandSideExpression -> Identifier
```

My State 26 looks like this:

```
item set 24 
AssignmentExpression -> LeftHandSideExpression .AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
AssignmentOperator -> .SIMPLE_ASSIGN
AssignmentOperator -> .COMPLEX_ASSIGN 
transitions ->  {"AssignmentOperator":61,"SIMPLE_ASSIGN":62,"COMPLEX_ASSIGN":63}

item set 25 
LogicalORExpression -> LogicalANDExpression .
LogicalANDExpression -> LogicalANDExpression .LOGICAL_AND EqualityExpression 
transitions ->  {"LOGICAL_AND":64}

item set 26 
LeftHandSideExpression -> Identifier .
PrimaryExpression -> Identifier . 
transitions ->  {}

item set 27 
LogicalANDExpression -> EqualityExpression .
EqualityExpression -> EqualityExpression .EQUALITY_OPERATOR RelationalExpression 
transitions ->  {"EQUALITY_OPERATOR":65}
```

How would I figure out the problem here and fix it?

I am using Jison, and I am running:
`jison -p lalr -t grammer/noa.bnf -t > log`

Interestingly I am also using `syntax-cli` which doesn't produce a reduce/reduce conflict, but still has trouble parsing.

Comment: Your question should include your grammar (or, ideally, a reduced version which shows the same problem). And "has trouble parsing" is not a very helpful problem description (although I understand that you're not asking about syntax-cli).

Answer (score 2):

What that is telling you is that there is some grammatical production in which the non-terminal `PrimaryExpression` (or some non-terminal whose expansion ends with `PrimaryExpression`) can be followed by a `SIMPLE_ASSIGN` (or some non-terminal whose expansion starts with `SIMPLE_ASSIGN`, although that seems unlikely). In that context, `Identifier` (whose expansion isn't shown) is ambiguous, because both `PrimaryExpression` and `LeftHandSideExpression` can expand to `Identifier`.

It's hard to guess what context that might be, but it should be reasonably simple to track down: just look at every non-terminal which can precede `SIMPLE_ASSIGN` until you find one which can end with `PrimaryExpression`.  (Not all such productions are errors, though. It's really highly dependent on the grammar.)